# Size of Independent set of sparse graphs with few triangles

Tags: reference-request, graph-algorithms, approximation-algorithms

Notations

1. $\alpha(G) = $  Max sized independent set of graph $G$.
2. $n(G) = $ Number of vertex in graph $G$.

*Theorem* (by Ajtai et al.): For a [triangle-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle-free_graph) graph $G$ and max degree being $\Delta$,

$$\alpha(G) \geq \frac{n(G)}{8\Delta}\log_2\Delta.$$

For a general graph, $\alpha(G) \geq n(G)/(\Delta+1)$, hence the above result is an improvement by a factor of $\log_2\Delta$. The proof of the above theorem is solely based on the triangle-free property of the graph.

**My question**: Can one obtain $\alpha(G)$ better than $n(G)/(\Delta+1)$ for graphs with only **few** triangles?

**EDIT 1** - I am looking for solutions where number of triangles, $t=O(n)$.

### **EDIT 2**

In the [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math.CO/0404325), lemma 6 has the following result.

*Theorem* : For a graph $G$ having maximum degree $\Delta$ and having at most T triangles,
$$\alpha(G) \geq \frac{n(G)}{10\Delta}\Bigg(\log_2\Delta - \frac{1}{2}\log_2\Big(\frac{T}{n(G)}\Big)\Bigg)$$

But I am not able to find the proof for the above theorem.

**EDIT3:** Thje proof can be found in "Random Graphs , 2nd edition", pg 332.

Comment: Small (and beautiful) proof for the theorem with triangle-free can be found in appendix A of the book "The Probabilistic Methods" by Noga Alon.

Comment: The very idea of this theorem is because graph is triangle free then many subgraphs are simply have an $\Omega(\Delta)$ independent set, so if you allow to have $O(n)$ triangle you will break this idea, and I doubt that if something similar holds (also I didn't thought about the conterexample, this is just guess).

Comment: you might have more success with this question on mathoverflow

Comment: The paragraph before the statement of the lemma you quote in Edit 2 cites the proof to page 296 of Bollobas's book _Random Graphs_ (his Lemma 15). Was it not there?

Comment: Sadly, I am not able to get hold of the first edition of Random Graphs (I have the 2nd edition though)

Comment: Are you still interested in this and is it still unsolved? I might be able to come up with a solution if I give it some thought, but I want to check that there's still reason to try.

Comment: @mobiusdumpling: In my Edit 3, I have given the page number of the book in which the proof is available. Thanks anyways!